# Best practice for fail-safe class loading

Tags: java

In my [Jodd library](https://jodd.org) I have a method that loads a class from given class name. Since this method has to be fail-safe (and smart;),  i coded several ways for loading a class in following order:

- using current thread classloader:

  `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(className);`
- if above fails, than `forName` is used:

  `Class.forName(className);`
- if above fails, then classloader of util class is used:

  `ClassLoaderUtil.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);`
- and, if a an optional Class argument is given, its classloader is used:

  `callingClass.getClassLoader().loadClass(className);`

Do you think this is a good order and/or should some steps be removed/added? Thanx.

Comment: After some investigation, i decided to choose the following approach, as described here: http://jodd.org/doc/class-loading-in-jodd.html I wanted to be able to load array classes as well. For this Class.forName is important, too.

Comment: @igt, your link does not contain content. Please update it so the readers can make use of it.

Comment: The new link: https://github.com/oblac/jodd-util/blob/master/src/main/java/jodd/util/ClassLoaderStrategy.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you just provide a method where the caller provides the `ClassLoader` directly - that would eliminate 1) and 4) (e.g. TCCL and callingClass.getClassLoader()).

Most libraries dealing with dynamic class loading provide two methods, one where the default lookup strategy is used as you describe it, and one where only the given ClassLoader is used.

Keep in mind that there may be expensive ClassLoaders, so every trial-and-error call of these loadClass() methods may trigger e.g. remote connections (for example in Applets) or even database lookups (yes, i've seen that too). In such cases, it's great to have a way to inject my own ClassLoader instance, e.g. for caching or blacklisting resources.

The order in which your default strategy works seems good to me. The most important one being definitely the TCCL, since this is the best approach when running in containers.

Comment: thanx. after reviewing my code and i am just about to add a method with a classloader as an argument, although such method would be dummy (just loadClass():); that why its missing in the first place. anyway, its nice to have a failsafe method - recently i had a situation when threads classloader was null, so another classloader had to be used:)

Comment: However, I still wonder if it is better to use #3 before #2... Somehow with Class.loadClass you do not know which classloader you will get?

Comment: Class.forName() is special because it uses the ClassLoader of the invoking class.  (See ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader() in Sun JDK)